# How to use the disable option from SortableJS in Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am using [element-ui-el-table-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-ui-el-table-draggable) to achieve the draggable effect on my el table, and it is working very fine.

Now, I want to use the disable option from SortableJS, but I dont know how to put these together.
Please check the below links.

[Github for Sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) and please search for "disable option"

[Live demo for disable option](https://jsbin.com/sewokud/edit?js,output)

Is this possible to do so? I am using Vue 2.6.11

Thanks a lot! Happy new year of 2022!

````
        <el-button type="primary" @click="switchState">{{ Disable }}</el-button>
        <p class="p-3" v-if="departmentlist">
          <ElTableDraggable>
            <el-table
              stripe
              class="table-responsive table"
              header-row-class-name="thead-light"
              :data="departmentlist"
              @row-click="row_clicked_event">
              <!-- <el-table-column label="ID" prop="IDn">
                <template v-slot="{ row }">
                  {{ row.IDn }}
                </template>
              </el-table-column> -->
              <el-table-column label="PLU" prop="PLU" :key="PLU"> </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column :label="$t('Name') + '1'" prop="Name1" :key="$t('Name') + '1'">
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column :label="$t('Name') + '2'" prop="Name2" :key="$t('Name') + '2'">
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column :label="$t('Sort Order')" prop="SortOrder" :key="$t('Sort Order')">
              </el-table-column>
              <el-table-column :label="$t('Remarks')" prop="Remarks" :key="$t('Remarks')">
              </el-table-column>
            </el-table>
          </ElTableDraggable>
        </p>
        <p class="p-3" v-else>
          {{ $t("No Records") }}
        </p>


<script>
import ElTableDraggable from 'element-ui-el-table-draggable'

export default {
  components: {
    ...
    ElTableDraggle
  },
  data() {
    ...
  },
  methods:{
    switchState(){
      // This should be where the magic happens I think
    }
  },
}
</script> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

To disable the sortable list, you have to add `disabled: true` as second argument.

```
var sortable = Sortable.create(list, {
  disabled: true
});
```